# visualize c++ data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, visualization, debuggervisualizer

I am looking for a program to help me debug a tree in c++. My tree has thousands of nodes and I want to view the tree as it forms and view problem nodes and branches. Operating system doesn't matter. Anyone know of a program that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what platform you are at, but [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) is pretty good with this, though can't say anything about its performance on huge sets.

Comment: I am using DDD now however I would like to "auto expand" all the nodes. I found a paper written on it but I can't find the actual feature.

Answer (score 1):

The only practical way I know is to write your own ! A good design solution is to implement a visitor design pattern. Then you can have different visitor like :

- a print visitor, that print your tree in the console (not practical as you say you have a lot of nodes)
- a serialize visitor : It will write your tree in a file.

You can then "debug" by calling the appropriate visitor at key points.

my2c

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Dot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language)?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a library called DSViz which is used to do this job. You can find it here: https://github.com/sunxfancy/DSViz

You need to write a few lines of code to use the API to generate a graphviz file so that you can draw the figure using addition tools.